# How to validate phone Number in textbox in Window phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to apply validation to a text box which stores a 10-digit phone number

How can I validate phone numbers in text boxes in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 3):

If you want use 10 number mobile validation than set in your **MaxLength="10"** and for phone number only **InputScope="TelephoneNumber"** this  all in XAML side like

```
<TextBox   Name="txtPhoneNo" Width="310"  Text=""  InputScope="TelephoneNumber" MaxLength="10" KeyDown="txtContactUsPhone_KeyDown" />
```

Now genrate keydown event of your Textbox and pest bellow code..

```
private void txtContactUsPhone_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString(), "[0-9]"))
                e.Handled = false;
            else e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Hope it will help you

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ill refer you to the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation), the question regards how to validate a phone number using a regex, in your case **one** way would be to use the regex within the setter of the property you are binding for the phone number and throw a ValidationException if it fails, when binding include the [ValidatesOnException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonexceptions%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) option

like

```
 public string PhoneNumber
 {
    get { return _phoneNumber; }
    set { 
       if (!IsValidPhoneNumber(value))
             throw new ValidationException("Invalid Phone Number");
       _phoneNumber = value;
     }
 }
```

with a binding expression something like

```
{Binding PhoneNumber, ValidatesOnException=True}
```

Comment: How does for example a TextBox react if its binding throws this exception. Will it be red or something?

Comment: Validate phone number which is user input by exception is a bad practice. It's kind of vexing exceptions - no really exceptional situation. I know it is a part of XAML, but I don't like it. I'd rather use bool var.

Comment: @rico yes the control template has built in styling that will show a red border and tooltip with the exception msg.

Comment: I believe there's no ValidationException in WP7 (at least not in Mango RC). You'll have to throw your own ones _and_ handle the BindingValidationError event.

Comment: @ehnmark you could very well be right, i just used it as an example, but any exception can be thrown...

Answer (score 0):

you can set the Textbox.Maxlength property,
and set the input scope to Numbers only.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;public static bool IsItNumber(string inputvalue){Regex isnumber = new Regex("[^0-9]");return !isnumber.IsMatch(inputvalue);}
```

or

```
public bool Main(string text)
```

{

```
  if ( !Regex.Match(text,@"^[1-9]\d{2}-[1-9]\d{2}-\d{4}$" ).Success )
  {
     return false
  }   else {
return true
}
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is gonna be simple. The easy method is to do is, add a eventhandler called "PreviewTextInput" in the textbox.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtbox_PhoneNum" PreviewTextInput="txtbox_PhoneNum_PreviewTextInput"/>
```

In the .cs file,

```
private void txtbox_PhoneNum_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
        e.Handled = reg.IsMatch(e.Text);
    }
```

If the e.Handled is true, you are entering alpha characters and finally you can do filtration by this.

Comment: Tunneling events are not available for Windows Phone.